# Why am I not getting email notification to new answers to my question?

Tags: support, answers, email

I have checked "Notify" check box with my email id in my question but I don't get any notification even though I get answers to that question. Why is it so? Is there problem in "AskUbuntu"'s part?

Answer (score 2):

You have not allowed us to send email to you:

https://askubuntu.com/users/10353/manohar-bhattarai?tab=prefs

Make sure the email notifications are checked otherwise you will not get email.